# How published app can use different system and same Jks File?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

My issue is that I have published an APK from my machine, and after that I have formated the machine. Now, I'm trying to create the sign APK from the same machine after formatting, but I am unable to do do.

I am using same keystore `.jks` file also I provide same `.jks` file and same alias name & password. I have also tried to do the same from other machines, but not able to do so.

Comment: what error you get when generating signed apk

Comment: your JKs file safe? from another machine ..

Comment: @Manish its giving  wrong password  error where as the same password is working fine when i am publishing  from the old system from where app was published for the  first time .

Comment: @DileepPatel yes  its safe . I have tried on both  same and another  machine

Comment: its nothing with different machine or same machine. some time .jks file might be corrupted. But its always generate signed apk .